# Creating installers or executables on Linux for every supported platform for a Kivy game

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, kivy

Is there a tool that creates installers from the source code of a Kivy game for all the different supported platforms with a single button press?

- Linux: `.deb`, `.rpm` or just a portable `.zip` file that contains a `.sh` script
- Windows: `.exe` (installer or portable executable)
- Mac: `.app` (installer or portable executable)
- and possibly Android and iOS

If not, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are possible, but I'm not sure what people are recommending right now - the Kivy website has instructions for pyinstaller (specifically on windows as I remember, but it works well on other platforms too), with the disadvantage that pyinstaller only supports python2 right now. You can use other tools too, I've seen some activity with e.g. nuitka, but I don't know the current state. Your best bet may be to ask on the kivy mailing list or irc, where some of the people using these tools are most likely to be around to comment.

I haven't seen anyone do .deb or .rpm. I'm fairly sure it shouldn't be too hard, though you'd need to do some stuff yourself to make it work since you'd quite likely be forging new ground.

Android and iOS are covered only by kivy's own build tools. These are fine on android, I can't comment on iOS.

Comment: I've found something; PyInstaller has experimental Python 3 support: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki ||| I just realized, I don't really need `.deb` and `.rpm`. Something like the Minecraft launcher, that (downloads and) runs the game file from the home directory, would work fine. I hope packaging Python applications becomes simpler, because it's a major hindrance for new developers and therefore weakens the Python and Kivy community. ||| Can I package with Nuitka on Linux? https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Packaging-Kivy-apps-written-in-Python-3,-targeting-Windows-using-Nuitka